# Recover the length of xml file

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I need to recover the length of a xml file. I have changed the code , please , I need help. It's really annoying.

```
try {

        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://sociable.co/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/android-wallpaper.png");
        URLConnection urlConnection = sourceUrl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        Log.v("the size of this file is : ", ""+file_size);

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
```

But when I use `log.v`, nothing is appeared in the logCat. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I edited your question, changing "recupere" to "recover"; I presume that's what you meant.  I suggest adding a tag to indicate what language this is.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is incorrect: `((File) xr)`... what if you do this:

```
sourceUrl.connect();
long length = sourceUrl.getContentLength();
```

Comment: just to be 100% sure... you have internet permissions, right?

Comment: It means that probably the server is not returning the length in the header... have you checked that?

Comment: Just checked that. Server is returning the header of length, which is 498565, so I am not sure why it gives returns -1 to you. Sorry.

Comment: It's done Cristian but which annoy me that the length is always 498565, i can't understand the reason . It's perhaps a default value of the length

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to parse a [png](http://sociable.co/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/android-wallpaper.png) file.

`edit`: See if your file gets downloaded properly

```
   void downloadXMLFile(String fileUrl){
              URL myFileUrl = null;
              try {

               myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
              } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
          }

          try {

               HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
               conn.setDoInput(true);
               conn.connect();
               int length = conn.getContentLength();
               InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
          } catch (IOException e) {

               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: i don't think so because i try this with an xml file and the length is always 0

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an XMLReader to a File. You get a ClassCastException. You should see that in your log. Christian is right (except that the method is `openConnection()` and not `connect()`).

Replace

```
long filesize = ((File) xr).length();
```

with

```
int filesize = sourceUrl.openConnection().getContentLength();
```

I have just tried it and it works.

Comment: I have always 0,
I just add this line to see the result :

int fileSizeInKB = filesize / 1024;
            Log.v("LENGTH:", ""+filesize);

Comment: Hey Mark, I try this but nothing in result.

Comment: Make sure you have an actual file, e.g. point your URL to any existing XML file like `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/android`. You may also want to step through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
long contentLength = Long.parseLong(httpconn.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));
```